# Why does a Developers Git Commit, Git Pull, Git Push always create a Git Merge?

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a developer who keeps committing, and every time he does - it does a git merge branch onto branch commit; every time. Even with his own code.

Ie, my history looks like this almost all the time. Occassionally one of my 6 devs will merge branch onto branch; but for most part they just have commits. This one dev, always always has it.

- **Dev Merge branch onto branch**
- **Dev Commit**
- **Dev Merge branch onto Branch**
- Dev Commit
- Other Commit
- Me Commit
- Other Commit
- Me Commit
- Me Commit
- Dev Merge Branch onto Branch
- Dev Commit
- Dev Merge branch onto branch
- Dev Comm

He was runnign 1.7; now 2.0

- git commit
- git pull
- git push

?
Any ideas?

Rest of us are fine in terminal (mac); GH win; GH win powershell, etc.

Its annoying because the garbage merges are creating a pain to be able to git revert.

Comment: Do the other guys use a `git rebase` after a `git fetch`, while the dev in question does a direct `git pull`?

Comment: nope - we all just git pull

Comment: ok, check my answer. Basically the dev in question is doing a pull after he has made local commits, causing his local and upstream branches to diverge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instruct the dev to make fresh commits only after he has done a pull.

`git` creates merge commits only if the local branch and the upstream branch diverge from a common point.  So, while the rest of the devs seem to be following this (i.e., they do a `git pull` before making any commits), the dev in question makes local commits and then does a `git pull`, therefore having the branches already diverged. Hence git is forced to recursively merge the changes, causing a merge commit to come into picture.

The other way to avoid this completely is to do a [`git fetch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch) coupled with a [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) organization wide, so that the history is maintained almost linearly without any merge commits.

Comment: So git pull, work, git commit. Then push? Then git pull? or would he have o git pull, work, commit, fetch, rebase.

Comment: Either got pull, work, git commit, git push. Or work, commit, git fetch, git rebase, git push. In your case, first is easier to implement.